# Bounding the dimension of a subspace associated with a hermitian form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that $H$ is an invertible hermitian (self adjoint) matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n×n}$. Define the hermitian (sesquilinear) form $[x,y]:=x^∗Hy$.
>
> Suppose $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that for every $v,u \in V, [u,v]=0$.
>
> Show $\dim(V)≤n/2$.

I don't really know where to start this problem, any help is appreciated.

(for what it's worth, this problem is not associated with any class I'm taking).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ be a basis of $V$. Show that the $2m$ vectors $v_i,\ldots,v_m,Hv_1,\ldots,Hv_m$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Let $\{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$ wrt to the usual innerproduct. Then $[u,v] = \langle u| Hv \rangle$. Suppose that $u := \sum_{i=1}^m ( \alpha_i v_i + \beta_i Hv_i ) = 0$.

Then $0 = \langle v_j| u \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m \big(\langle v_j|\alpha_i v_i \rangle + \langle v_j |\beta_i Hv_i\rangle \big)= a_j +0$.

Thus $u = \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i Hv_i=0$. Since $H$ is invertible and ${v_i}$ is a basis, $H[v_1, ..., v_m]$ is a basis. Thus $\beta_i = 0$.

Since $\mathbb{C}^n$ can only have $n$ linearly independent vectors, we must have $m \leq n/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it made the problem pretty straightforward. Though, why would one have guessed that these vectors would be linearly independent in the first place? I don't see the geometry of what $H$ is doing.

Also, it doesn't appear that I used $H$ being hermitian anywhere. Hmmm.

Comment: @student If we consider $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$, then by a suitable change of basis, the sesquilinear form can be viewed as a Riemannian pseudometric. So there may be really some geometry behind the question. But I simply view $x^\ast Hy$ as the inner product between $x$ and $Hy$. So it is natural to consider the $2m$ vectors in the answer. You have noticed that $H$ being Hermitian is not used in the proof. That's a good observation. I didn't notice that. Perhaps the question setter expected a proof in which $H$ is diagonalized.